# Template fail for non-exist php error

Tags: php, smarty, propel

im working with Propel and Smarty. I have a `servicios.php` file, that only contains:

```
include('private/autoload.php');

// Servicios Todos
$servicios = ServicioQuery::Create()->orderByTitulo(Criteria::ASC)->find()->toArray();
$smarty->assign('servicios',$servicios);

// Servicio a mostrar
$servQry = ServicioQuery::Create();
if($url->getParam(3) == '') {
    $servicio = $servQry->findOneByIdservicio(1);
}else{
    $servicio = $servQry->findOneBySlug($url->getParam(3));
}

// Error Line ?
$servicio = $servicio->toArray();


$smarty->assign('servicio',$servicio);

$smarty->display('templates/servicio.tpl');
```

The file `servicio.tpl` contains:

```
<html>
<head>
    {include file="html_head.tpl"}
</head>
<body>
....
<h2>{$servicio.Titulo}</h2>
<div class="span3">
     <img class="borderFoto" src="assets/img/servicios/{$servicio.Slug}.jpg" alt="{$servicio.Slug}.jpg" />
</div>
<div class="span7">
     {$servicio.Descripcion}
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

In the `html_head.tpl`:

```
<title>Pilar Medicina Est&eacute;tica</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arvo' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/style.css">
```

So, the problem is that, the Css styles dont load. With Firebug show that instead of print the Css code, print:

> **Fatal error**: Call to a member function toArray() on a
>   non-object in
>   **/media/Datos/www/PilarMedicinaEstetica/owner/servicios.php** on
>   line **15**

But, the error is rare, because the data is displayed correctly and the `var_dump` of `$servicio` dont mark errors:

> array(7) { ["Idservicio"]=> int(1) ["Idsitio"]=> int(1) ["Titulo"]=>
>   string(15) "Servicio demo 1" ["Descripcion"]=> string(979) "Nulla
>   commodo commodo iaculis...eget pellentesque nunc nisi ac sem."
>   ["Slug"]=> string(17) "servicio_demo_uno" ["Shares"]=> int(1)
>   ["Activo"]=> bool(true) }

In the index.php, do the equal steps, and works. Why here not ? Any ideas ?.

Comment: `Call to a member function toArray() on a non-object` Your object is not an object but already an array?

Comment: @Bondye `$servicio` is a object of "Servicio" class. If i try pass the object, Smarty says: **Fatal error: Cannot use object of type Servicio as array in...**

Comment: Uhmm instead of using `{$servicio.Titulo}` can't pass the object instead of creating an array. Like so `{$servicio->Titulo}`? Else try to `print_r($servicio)` before and after the `$servicio->toArray()` and compare them.

Answer (score 0):

The error was that i pass an wrong slug, and the query returns an empty collection jiji.